# How to add row on defaulttablemodel

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable, tablemodel

Can anyone please tell me how to add row on defaulttablemodel?i use resultset to retrieve data from database and `rs.getString()` to get them..and also i want this table update automatically as soon i pressed the button..

```
public void table(){

    try{

        rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM payments;");

        Vector<String> header = new Vector<String>();

        header.add("PAYMENT"); 
        header.add("AMOUNT");
        header.add("MODIFIER");
        header.add("DATE MODIFIED");

        Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new  Vector<Vector<Object>>();

        while(rs.next()) {

            Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>();

            row.add(rs.getString("description"));
            row.add(rs.getString("amount")); 
            row.add(rs.getString("remarks")); 
            row.add(rs.getString("date"));


            dtm.addRow(row);

        } // loop

        dtm.setDataVector(data , header);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        scrollPane.setBounds(0,0,490,250);
        panel.add(scrollPane);
        validate();

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error in table: "+e);
    }//try and catch

}
```

Comment: dtm is my defaulttaqblemodel

Comment: the table only show the header not the row..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your `data` Vector to store all your results/rows and then `dtm.setDataVector(data , header);` after the loop.

Change your code

```
dtm.addRow(row);
```

to

```
data.add(row);
```

Basically, your code have to be

```
    Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new  Vector<Vector<Object>>();

    while(rs.next()) {

        Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>();

        row.add(rs.getString("description"));
        row.add(rs.getString("amount")); 
        row.add(rs.getString("remarks")); 
        row.add(rs.getString("date"));


        data.add(row); // add each result/row to data Vector

    } // loop

    dtm.setDataVector(data , header); // load all the table rows to DefaultTableModel
```